# The madurai office of Dinakaran

Tags: word-usage

I was reading an article and there was a sentence;

> It is therefore gratifying that the Madras High Court has broken the mould to set aside the perverse acquittal of all those involved in the attack on **the Madurai office of Dinakaran**, a Tamil daily, in 2007 and sentenced nine of them to life.

I think **Madurai office of Dinakaran** is used to say the office of Dinakaran that is situated in madurai, but to me its usage looks very awkward. If its usage is correct it would be fine to write **The india office of google, The india office of facebook**

Thanks in advance..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those usages you use as other examples of the same pattern are fine. You often hear about news agencies and broadcasters and their "Washington bureau" or "Delhi bureau" (or you do if you're reading/listening to certain things).

This is the use of the city/country/state name as an **attributive noun**. It is using one noun to indicate an attribute - location, purpose, etc. - of another noun. For example, one my press trousers in a **trouser press**, or if you're in your study and there's noise outside, you might want to shut the **study door**. In your kitchen, you'll probably find a **kitchen sink**, and perhaps a **vegetable knife**.